# Dynamically scale worker_dynos using Rails 4.2 and active_job

Tags: heroku, rails-activejob

Heroku says that worker_dynos never sleep -- is there a way to dynamically scale the worker_dynos by scaling to 0 when they have 0 queued processes?

Or simpler, start & stop at certain times of day?

Comment: which queue backend do you use? For example this could use with Sidekiq to auto scale your worker: https://github.com/JustinLove/autoscaler

Comment: I was using SuckerPunch, I'm trying redis and https://github.com/dtmtec/dyno_scaler now. Autoscaler looks nice